# drupal 7 taxonomy term translation in user profile field i18n

Tags: drupal, internationalization, translation, multilingual, taxonomy

Problem: in the user profile page taxonomy term United Kingdom is displaying only in default language but not translating.

I have vocabulary **Countries** that has "Localize" option. 
I've translated all the terms. For example: United Kingdom = Vereinigtes Königreich = Royaume-Uni = Великобритания.

I've made a menu Countries - so in language versions menu items are displaying translated and ok! 
But in the **user profile page** Field Country is displaying only in default language and not translating if I go to lang versions. 
The labels are displaying translated so I have Country, Land, Pays, Страна - labels. But the term United Kingdom is displaying only in english.

I am using Internationalization i18n, Taxonomy translation, Field Translation, String translation, Multilingual select modules.

here I have two methods language selection /admin/config/regional/language/configure : url and by default.

/admin/config/regional/i18n/select here i have checked both Select nodes by language Select taxonomy terms by language

I've tried to use Entity Translation but it is very big and difficult and not that I need.

May be there is User translation module?

Please what should I do to translate terms in user profile fields drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass your variable trough t() function in your template, where you are printing it out and it will become translatable. It's work-around, but it can save time and nerves.

Comment: i think your answer is very abstract. I have translated taxonomy terms and want to get translatable user field. i know about t() please how to change my user.tpl.php ?

Comment: Now your question is abstract - how to change the file?! With text editor of course.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use **Profile2** and **Profile2 Translation** modules and using field Country in Main profile (Profile2) I've solved this problem.
But Profile2 is not useful for me cause it makes new page in user editing page and lot of users have already set up field Country I do not whant to work with database.
If I knew I was using Profile2 + Profile2 Translation first!
May be you give recommendations how to get it with Profile module?